# PHP E-Mail Client - Overcoming slow send/receive

Tags: php, email, smtp, imap

I have developed a CRM that is used with a marketing website similar to manta.com. The CRM has a built-in email client. Basically it matches names and emails to addresses on file, and if the email is from a customer it loads their account information next to the email.

The entire system works, but is in some cases slow. Because each "region" of the country is managed by a different company, the software connects to several different mail servers, all of which behave differently.

In some cases (mostly with godaddy servers) it takes a very long time to send an email. It also takes a long time to load the inbox if they have a lot of messages (500+), even if it is paged.

I am using pear Mail::Factory smtp to send, and the built in php imap functions to receive.

I am thinking for outgoing messages I will just store the emails into a db and then have a cron script send it out, then they can send their email and move on right away.

Does anyone have any ideas/concepts for handling large inboxes via IMAP and php? I will have no control over the mail servers themselves, but have full control over the server that the CRM is on.

I am not looking for code, just concepts if you have them.

It is Linux (ubuntu), apache, mysql, php. I can use Zend if needed.

Comment: Can't you just use the local SMTP server to send the email?

Also, 500 emails doesn't seem like a very large inbox. However, do you have to download the headers from every single email each time? If so, you really need to look into caching it.

Comment: No I can't use the local SMTP. Depending on the person sending it, the domain it comes from is different. For example someone in New York may be bobdole@newyorksales.com and someone from Los Angeles may be maryjane@californiasales.com

Because of the differing domains it needs to go out from their mail server, or else I'll end up opening another can of worms with SPF and other email validation issues.

The simple way to look at it is a web-based Outlook, where they put in their mail server, username, and password and it connects their account to the CRM.

Comment: Well, technically you can send email from any domain you want by inserting the appropriate mail headers. The only restrictions would be if there is an SPF record for that domain that doesn't include your server's IP address.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you edited your comment before I posted that one. Another option would be to make the mail from noreply@yourhost.com and make reply-to be bobdole@newyorksales.com.

Comment: Mike I will look into caching the incoming emails. Are you thinking I just save the header info (to, from, subject, date) and just load new ones when they open their inbox? Does php have the ability to load emails after a certain date? I also agree 500 emails isn't a large inbox (I have 7000 in mine), but with godaddy I get a 2-3 minute delay before it can get the message subjects.

Comment: About caching, I was talking only about the message header info, not the whole message (unless you want to). However you probably want to look into the [imap_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) function, which allows you to obtain only the relevant messages.

Comment: Ok I'll look at the imap_search function. When it is working smoothly I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a combination of caching the emails and using the imap_fetch_overview function which omits the body of the email. This seems to eliminate any issues with the lag. I can also use it to page the results so I am only loading a small number (25-50) at a time. Thanks for the help.